# div in html 5 won't display from css3 file

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web page using html 5 and an external css3 stylesheet.

I've created a div to display a rounded corner box. It displays fine when the css div code is in the html document. But as soon as I transfer it to the css3 stylesheet the box disappears. I've been searching for an answer for a couple of hours now and cannot work out whats wrong.

Here is my html code...

```
<style type="text/css"> 
div
{
    border:8px solid #000000;
    padding:10px 10px; 
    background:#ffffff;
    width:500px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div><h1>WELCOME TO THE WEBSITE</h1></div>
```

But as soon as I move this portion

```
div
{
    border:8px solid #000000;
    padding:10px 10px; 
    background:#ffffff;
    width:500px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}
```

over to my css file, and remove 
       from the html file.

The div box disappears. All other elements defined in the css file are displaying properly so I know the file is linked. I just don't know why this div won't display.

thanks for the reply. The full css code is

```
body
{
background-image:url(roses.png);
background-repeat:repeat top;
background-colour:#ffffff;
background-attachment:scroll;
}

h1
{
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #efefef;
}

div
{
border:8px solid #000000;
padding:10px 10px; 
background:#ffffff;
width:500px;
margin: auto;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}

#para1
{
text-align:center;
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Please post your stylesheet. The problem most likely is in there.

Comment: have you tried taking out the other styles in the stylesheet, to eliminate them as possible cause of the problem?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I neded up saving the stylesheet and not being able to get the stuff back I removed with undo, so had to write the whole thing out again.
Ive also tried giving the div an id and a class but that doesnt change anything.

Comment: I should add Im viewing the web page locally. Its not uploaded to a server yet. Every other change I make in the css is reflected on the web page immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Given everything you've said in the question, it sounds to me as if the browser is caching an older version of the stylesheet.

Check in Firebug to see what it thinks is in the stylesheet.

Try loading the stylesheet's URL directly into its own browser window, refresh it if necessary, and check that the new code is in place.

The only other possibility I can think of is that there's some sort of error at the end of your stylesheet code which is preventing the browser from parsing the styles after it.

This is possible, but I can't verify it without seeing the whole of your CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code I can't be sure, but one thing I'd change in your CSS is the order of the two lines relating to your rounded border.

You should always have the `border-radius` directive **after** any vendor-specific ones. In other words, the `-moz-border-radius:25px` line needs to come first.

Why this works in one scenario and not in another I'm not entirely sure, but there are quirks out there… What browser are you previewing in?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Im using Firefox 7 to view the page.

Also can someone tell me how I give each div its own identity, Ive tried .divname and div.divname and neither seems to work.

Comment: Ive worked out how to name the divs, I still need to get them working from the css files though :(

Comment: So have you tried editing your CSS per my post? And reviewing the page in Firebug (or similar) to be sure that the correct CSS is getting loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Ive given the divs separate names and now everything seems to be working ok from within the css file. Happy days :)